# How to set initialProperties in RCTRootView using Wix React Native Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I want to pass properties from native ios code to react native.

Here is the guide https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios#passing-properties-from-native-to-react-native which states that you should use initialProperties in RCTRootView

Here is how I start the ios app with react native navigation (7.1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
    [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrapWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];  
    return YES;
}
```

So how can I set `initialProperties` of the `RCTRootView` with `ReactNativeNavigation` ?

Thanks in advance